# Why does not work correctly the cleanup function?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

In the custom hook, there is a cleanup function, if the  component is unmounted, then the states won't be updated.

Can you tell me why is the `if` condition in the catch block all the time skipped? The default value for the `isCancelled` is `false` , so it should work, but it does not. I have to get out the `dispatch` function from the `if` condition, and put before the condition. Why is that? I don't cancel the component, so the isCancelled should be `false`, but instead is `true`. Where has been changed the `isCancelled` from `false` to `true`. Thanks!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../firebase/config';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';

export const useLogin = () => {
  const [isCancelled, setIsCancelled] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
  const { dispatch } = useAuth();

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    console.log(auth.currentUser);
    setError(null);
    setIsPending(true);

    //sign user out
    try {
      const res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log(auth.currentUser);
      console.log(res.user);

      //update state
      if (!isCancelled) {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.user });
        setIsPending(false);
        setError(null);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (!isCancelled) {
        console.log(error.message);
        setError(error.message);
        setIsPending(false);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setIsCancelled(true);
  }, []);

  return { login, error, isPending };
};
```

Comment: What do you have in `useAuth()`? I suspect there might be something there that is setting isCancelled. Not something that is causing the issue but just wanted to point out: the useEffect block is redundant because by the time component unmounts, the state `isCancelled` is already gone.

Comment: useAuth() is just a global context, where the data from user are saved. So it returns the useContext.

Comment: await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password); 
if this part isn't a throwing error it will never go to catch
as try is executed first and then catch
so as there is no issue is try why it will't go into catch block.

Comment: I talk about the if condition in the try block not about the if condition in the catch block.